# navigator notification alert not working in Cordova

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I'm trying to print an alert with Cordova and it only works if I emulate my app with Ripple Chrome extension.

In my Samsung Galaxy S3, nothing happens when I click the button.

I'm using Cordova 3.6.3-0.2.13.
I've added to my project the following plugins:
org.apache.cordova.dialogs and
org.apache.cordova.vibration.
(if I type "cordova plugins ls" they both appear)

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

      function getInfo() {
         navigator.notification.alert(
                 'Model: ' + device.model,  // message
                 null,         // callback
                 'Info',            // title
                 'Ok'                  // buttonName
         );
     }
    </script>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
    <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
    <title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="app">
        <h1>Apache Cordova</h1>
        <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
            <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
            <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
        </div>
        <button id="gobutton" type="button" onclick="getInfo()">CLICK ME</button>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

While my index.js is:

```
var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    // Bind Event Listeners
    //
    // Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
    // 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    // deviceready Event Handler
    //
    // The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
    // function, we must explicitly call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    },
    // Update DOM on a Received Event
    receivedEvent: function(id) {
        var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
        var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
        var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

        listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
        receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

        console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
    }
};

app.initialize();
```

Could you help me? Thanks in advance

Comment: Try moving your `getInfo()` function to the bottom of your `index.js`

Answer (score 0):

Dawson's comment should work.

As you can see at the Cordova documentation page:
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/cordova_notification_notification.md.html#notification.alert

The code:

```
navigator.notification.alert
```

is AFTER loading the cordova library.